# Trying to use functions inside a class, but 'name is not defined error' keeps popping up?

Tags: python

I am writing a class that involves a few external functions, and I store them in the form of a dictionary

```
class Number:
    def __add__(self,other):
        if self.type_tag == other.type_tag:
            return self.add(other)
        elif (self.type_tag, other.type_tag) in self.adders:
            return self.cross_apply(other, self.adders)

    def __mul__(self,other):
        if self.type_tag == other.type_tag:
            return self.mul(other)
        elif (self.type_tag, other.type_tag) in self.multipliers:
            return self.cross_apply(other, self.multipliers)

    def cross_apply(self,other,cross_funcs):
        #select appropriate function from adders dictionary
        cross_func = cross_funcs[(self.type_tag, other.type_tag)]
        return cross_func(self.other)

    adders = {("com", "rat"):add_complex_rational,
              ("rat", "com"):add_rational_complex
             }
    multipliers = {
              ("com", "rat"):mul_complex_rational,
              ("rat", "com"):mul_rational_complex
             }
             
def add_complex_rational(c,r):
    return Complex_Real_Imaginary(c.real + r.numer/r.denom, c.imag)

def add_rational_complex(r,c):
    return add_complex_rational(c,r)

def mul_complex_rational(c,r):
    r_magnitude = r.numer/r.denom
    r_angle = 0
    if r_magnitude < 0:
        r_magnitude = -r_magnitude
        r_angle = pi
    return Complex_Magnitude(c.magnitude * r_magnitude, c.angle * r_angle)

def mul_rational_complex(r,c):
    return mul_complex_rational(c,r)
```

However, whenever I tried to run the code the error message `'add_complex_rational' is not defined` keeps showing up and I have no idea why as they are already defined in the file. Please give me some hints on where I got wrong, thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: If you mean `add_complex_rational` then it is not yet defined when the body of the class is executed. Simply switch the order, define the class last...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that external functions used in classes have to be put before the class code

Comment: @Mattmmmmm **all names** have to be defined before you use them *anywhere* in Python. This has nothing to do with functions specifically, or really class definitions

Comment: This shows up because you are creating class level structures, ie: `adders = ...`. which are executed when the file is imported. If you were only accessing these functions from inside member functions of `Number`, then this would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Define all your functions before class like this. It happens because you call the function before you initialize it.

```
def your_function():
    pass

class ClassName:
    pass
```

Answer (score -3):

Tab the methods in appropriately. Python thinks `add_complex_rational` is not in the class, but a standalone method.

Comment: They're not supposed to be in the class. They don't have a `self` argument.

Comment: And you would have to access it as `Number.add_complex_rational`